# Use notification ID to change logo & text

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'd like to know how applications like Facebook change their notification title & logo depending on the content.

For example, in Facebook, if you get tagged you get another title & another logo.

I assume it should be possible with notify to create a unique notification. 
Though I can't find any clear examples for this.

My GenerateNotification:

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String url) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ShowChange.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra ("url",url);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this:(this is basically your code with some modifications)

public static void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String url,int icon_from_drawable) {
    int icon = icon_from_drawable;

```
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ShowChange.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra ("url",url);
// set intent so it does not start a new activity
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent intent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

// Play default notification sound
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

//notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

// Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

}

If you targeting your app for API LEVEL>=11, then use Notification.Builder
refer here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html
One more point the above code will keep updating the same notification object because the notify method of notification manager is taking always the same id i.e 0, so the same object of notification will be updated.

Comment: Good idea, thnx, I will send the icon name with GCM on php as extra info, i try in a few mins:P

Comment: Thnx, ur idea solved mine problem. I get the image now from my server, which i recieve as string, than i parse it like this to int:  int icon = context.getResources().getIdentifier(icon_from_drawable, "drawable", context.getPackageName()); which will parse it to int & get the png from the server:)