# PushApps Android push notification sample

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pushapps

I implemented [PushApps](http://www.pushapps.mobi) Android SDK.
All is well and working, but I want to create a notification by myself without using:

```
PushManager.buildNotification(intent.getExtras(), context,
                                        NOTIFICATION_ID, R.drawable.notification_icon,
                                        notificationIntent);
```

specific - I want to show a custom layout using the data received in the

```
intent.getExtras()
```

Thanks!

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637326/andriod-using-notify-id-to-change-logo-text/16638416#16638416)

Answer (score 1):

In order to show your own custom notification, you can take control over the PushAppsMessage interface. By doing that, you can show your own custom message with special layouts and more!. Checkout this article - [How To Create Android Push Notifications With Custom View?](http://wiki.pushapps.mobi/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5407074).